# Adding items of multiple lists

Tags: linear-algebra

I have multiple lists, like {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} and {7,8,9}.

I would like to add all the elements together. So the result should be: {12,15,18}

In case that the value of any of the items is `Nil`, the addition should be ignored or it should be added with 0.

How can I do this?

Comment: By manually adding them up?

Comment: @Tavish I can't do it manually, since the values are dynamic. They could be {a, b, c}

Comment: What do you want the result to be when one of the lists is $\{ a,b,c\}$?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are hoping for here.  If you have two lists, $\{a_a, \cdots, a_n\}$ and $\{b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$ then their sum is $\{a_1+b_1, \cdots, a_n+b_n\}$.
-

Comment: @Tavish then the result of the added numbers or variables should be saved in a variable. e.g. something like this: x = {a,b,c} + {d,e,f} + {g,h,i}

Comment: Maybe you are asking a coding question?

Comment: @lulu yup, you are right. But I need to explain my code in a mathematical way. That's why I am asking.

Comment: I think you will be better served by asking this on a site devoted to whichever programming language you wanted.  As a general matter, if your lists are $L_1, \cdots, L_k$  then their sum is the list $S$ with $S[i]=\sum_{j=1}^n L_j[i]$ where, if $i$ exceeds the length of the list $L$ we define $L[i]=0$.

Comment: @lulu ok great, that already helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped.  I note that what I wrote has a typo....the sum is meant to run to $k$, not $n$, where $k$ is the number of lists.